# How to fetch day from selected date in Delivery Date extension in Magento?

Tags: magento, date

I want to fetch day from the selected date in Delivery Date Extension from Aheadworks in Magento.

According to this day, I want to add extra cost in Grand Total while checkout at the last step. I am using a one page checkout process in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Ask Aheadworks for support. It's their extension.